# Convert cv::Vec4f line to cv::Vec2f

Tags: opencv, geometry

I have a pair of Cartesian coordinates that represent a line in an image. I would like to convert this line to polar form and draw it over the image.

e.g

```
  cv::Vec4f line {10,20,60,70};
    float x1 = line[0];
    float y1 = line[1];
    float x2 = line[2];
    float y2 = line[3];
```

I want this line to be represented in cv::Vec2f form(rho,theta).

Taking care of rho & theta with all possible slopes.

Given are the image dimensions :: w and h;

w = image.cols
h = image.rows

How can I achieve this.

N.B: We can also assume that the line can be an extended one running across the image.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
        {
            int x1 = lines[i][0];
            int y1 = lines[i][1];
            int x2 = lines[i][2];
            int y2 = lines[i][3];


            float d = sqrt(((y1-y2)*(y1-y2)) + ((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)) );
            float rho = (y1*x2 - y2*x1)/d;
            float theta = atan2(x2 - x1,y1-y2) ;

            if(rho < 0){
                theta *= -1;
                rho *= -1;
            }

             linv2f.push_back(cv::Vec2f(rho,theta));
         }
```

The above approach doesnt give me results when I plot the lines I dont get the lines that are overlapping their original vec4f form.

I use this to convert vec2f to vec4f for testing :

```
cv::Vec4f cvtVec2fLine(const cv::Vec2f& data, const cv::Mat& img)
{
    float const rho = data[0];
    float const theta = data[1];

    cv::Point pt1,pt2;

    if((theta < CV_PI/4. || theta > 3. * CV_PI/4.)){
        pt1 = cv::Point(rho / std::cos(theta), 0);
        pt2 = cv::Point( (rho - img.rows * std::sin(theta))/std::cos(theta), img.rows);
    }else {
        pt1 = cv::Point(0, rho / std::sin(theta));
        pt2 = cv::Point(img.cols, (rho - img.cols * std::cos(theta))/std::sin(theta));
    }

    cv::Vec4f l;
    l[0] = pt1.x;
    l[1] = pt1.y;
    l[2] = pt2.x;
    l[3] = pt2.y;
    return l;
}
```

Comment: I've corrected my answer and made example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rho-theta equation has form

```
x * Cos(Theta) + y * Sin(Theta) - Rho = 0
```

We want to represent equation 'by two points' into rho-theta form ([page 92 in pdf here](http://izt.ciens.ucv.ve/ecologia/Archivos/References-I-math/books-math/Math/Polyanin_Manzhirov-Handbook_of_Mathematics_for_Engineers_and_Scientists.pdf)). If we have

```
 x * A + y * B - C = 0
```

and need coefficients in trigonometric form, we can divide all equation by magnitude of (A,B) coefficient vector.

```
D = Length(A,B) = Math.Hypot(A,B)
x * A/D + y * B/D - C/D = 0
```

note that `(A/D)^2 + (B/D)^2 = 1` - basic trigonometric equality, so we can consider  `A/D` and `B/D` as cosine and sine of some angle theta.

Your line equation is

```
(y-y1) * (x2-x1) - (x-x1) * (y2-y1) = 0
or
x * (y1-y2) + y * (x2-x1) - (y1 * x2  - y2 * x1) = 0
let
D = Sqrt((y1-y2)^2 + (x2-x1)^2)
so
Theta = ArcTan2(x2-x1, y1-y2)
Rho = (y1 * x2  - y2 * x1) / D
```

**edited**

If Rho is negative, change sign of Rho and **shift Theta by Pi**

Example:

```
 x1=1,y1=0, x2=0,y2=1
 Theta = atan2(-1,-1)=-3*Pi/4
 D=Sqrt(2)
 Rho=-Sqrt(2)/2  negative =>

 Rho = Sqrt(2)/2
 Theta = Pi/4
```

Back substitutuon - find points of intersection with axes

```
0 * Sqrt(2)/2 + y0 * Sqrt(2)/2 - Sqrt(2)/2 = 0
x=0 y=1

x0 * Sqrt(2)/2 + 0 * Sqrt(2)/2 - Sqrt(2)/2 = 0
x=1 y=0
```

Comment: Can you please help in regards with the explanation, I do understand what you have written, But I would like to learn more and clear some concepts. I would be grateful if you could refer to some paper/book or website. I want to know why rho is divided by D.

Comment: Added some explanations. In the first time I read information about rho-theta equation in `Mathematical handbook for scientists and engineers` by G.Korn,T.Korn. Linked text is very similar to that book.